# list picker issue in windows phone value hidden

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I have a `dropdown menu` and a `ListPicker` with two values: A and B.
When I select something from the menu, my values appear. When I select a value, it appears in a textbox (A or B).
If I click to top of value A, the value dissapears, why?

This is what I have in `XAML`:

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Select" Visibility="Collapsed" >
                            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="A"/>
                            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="B"/>
   </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

In the code, the `ListPicker` is set to visibile, `TextBox` gets the selected value and shows the content.

I've made [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HShcTcEGaR4) to explain this issue. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Could you put you code here as well + all xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that might help you

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding}"/>

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="Select" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionChanged="Select_SelectionChanged">
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="A"/>
                        <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="B"/>
```

Then write the following c# code on the SelectionChanged Event Handler for the 
listpicker.

```
private void Select_SelectionChanged()
{
    myTextBox.DataContext = ((ListPickerItem)Select.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
}
```

or if if refuses try this one out

```
private void Select_SelectionChanged()
{
    myTextBox.DataContext = Select.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```